# Multiple MVC 3 Areas and getting resource cannot not be found on the default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have an mvc 3 application. I have one Admin area and it is working correctly. There are also controllers and views as per the default project configuration outside of the areas. This also works fine. But when I add a new Area under Areas, The controllers inside the areas continue to work but for the ones outside I am getting resource cannot be found.

Am I missing something here?

```
public mycode  //put some areas and controllers here 
               //4 spaces in front of code
{
}
```

produces this error message:

> An exception occured...  (line starts with a > is a block which is good for exceptions)

My default and area routes are being registered in global.

Comment: We'll need to see some code and the specific error message.  Since you appear to be new to the website, welcome to Stackoverflow.  I've slightly modified your question for you to *fill in the blanks* with information that would help answer your question.

Comment: thanks Erik. False alarm the routes continue to work if I add multiple areas, a key value from my routes just got deleted and I did not notice.